# npm install for a forked library does not install it completely

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am working on a private node js project made using nest js. I am using the [node-coap library](https://github.com/coapjs/node-coap) which I have forked into my company's github profile. I am installing it into the project using npm install /node-coap, but it installs it incompletely into my node_modules folder. As a result, my compilation is unsuccessful and I get this error:

```
2023-07-11 14:32:54 src/coap/coap.controller.ts:2:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'coap' or its corresponding type declarations.

2023-07-11 14:32:54

2023-07-11 14:32:54 2 import { Server } from 'coap';

2023-07-11 14:32:54                          ~~~~~~

2023-07-11 14:32:54 

2023-07-11 14:32:54 src/coap/coap.module.ts:4:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'coap' or its corresponding type declarations.

2023-07-11 14:32:54 

2023-07-11 14:32:54 4 import * as coap from 'coap';

2023-07-11 14:32:54                         ~~~~~~
```

This is what I see in my node modules (it has named itself coap):[Installed coap module inside my node_modules folder, shows only some files from the many on github.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJUQR.png)

I can't figure out how to install it properly, and this has become a huge blocker in my development tasks. Kindly assist!

I tried these solutions at [this website](https://blaipratdesaba.com/how-to-use-an-npm-node-module-that-has-been-forked-b7dd522fdd08) and [this website](https://dev.to/dannyaziz97/how-the-hell-do-i-use-my-forked-npm-package-4pei) but to no avail. Finally, I tried adding a script of `"prebuild":"npm run build"`, and it gives me this error when I install the forked node-coap, clearly because it cannot find it inside node_modules.

````
npm ERR! path /home/User/Work/project/project-module/node_modules/coap
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run build
npm ERR! > coap@1.3.0 build
npm ERR! > tsc -b
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! error TS5083: Cannot read file '/home/User/Work/project/project-module/node_modules/coap/tsconfig.json'.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 2023-07-11T10_40_22_375Z-debug-0.log```
````

Comment: Do you list all necessary files in `package.json`?

Comment: @jabaa I believe I have done i. Basically, a work colleague had already forked it using their own account and it was working fine. But since they left and cleared that forked library, we forked it to the organization's account and changed the package.json to point there. That is where the issue is coming up.

Comment: For some reason, now that I installed the same package directly from npm, it installs all of the files completely. Still, I'd like to know why the previous method was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I installed the same package directly from npm, it adds it to package.json on its own and it installs all of the files completely.